# Maximum number arraylist

Tags: java

Hello i have to get maximum number from arraylist in Java . 
ia m getting error T- is not within bound implement java . lang . comparable is there any other way to sort arralist . Here is my code sample .

```
private void CreateHighestScorePlayer(LinearLayout layoutForHighScore) {
    HighScoreManager highScoreManager = HighScoreManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<Score> scores = highScoreManager.getScore();
    Collections.sort(scores);
    scores.get(scores.size() -1);

}
```

Comment: You need to define a custom comparator for the Score class.

Comment: i know it is there any other way to sort it

Comment: No. The `Score` class must either be `Comparable` or you must provide a `Comparator`. Java doesn't know how to sort your class by itself. How should it sort it, on which fields? You must tell it by implementing `Comparable` or passing a custom `Comparator`. What's the trouble with that?

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.sort` is a generic method with the following signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

This means that you must pass as an argument a `List<T>` where `T` extends `Comparable<? super T>`.

So you have two solutions, you can turn your `Score` class into

```
class Score implements Comparable<Score> {

  public int compareTo(Score other) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or you can use `Collection.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T> c)` by passing a custom `Comparator` for your score class.

The first solution is better assuming you have control over `Score` class since it will give a score the feature to be naturally ordered with other scores.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your `Score` object implement `Comparable` and then call [Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) on your `ArrayList`. Or you can call the overloaded version of `max` with a `Comparator`. Either way, your code needs to know what makes one `Score` object bigger, smaller, or equal to another.

We actually created a video tutorial with sample code on `Comparable` and `Comparator` you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq0ArQhhWzU). The key thing is understanding the difference between the two in deciding which to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the maximum element, you should use [Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) method. It has a version that takes a custom comparator as an argument.

Something like this:

```
Score result = Collections.max(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Score score1, Score score2) {
        // Compare them here
    }
});
```

Comment: Collection.max same issue

Comment: @user3826166 Are you using the version with a comparator?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to find the highest score you can use a simple Java 8 construct. If your `Score` class looks something like the following:

```
public static class Score {
    private final int score;

    Score(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Then, you can `stream` your `List<Score>` like this:

```
List<Score> scores =
        Arrays.asList(new Score(100), new Score(200), new Score(50));

final Optional<Score> max =
        scores.stream().max((score1, score2) -> Integer.compare(score1.getScore(), score2.getScore()));

if (max.isPresent()) {
    Score score = max.get();

    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Handle when there are no scores

}
```

This also uses a `Comparator` as described in some of the other answers. The `Comparator` is constructed as a lamdba like this:

```
(score1, score2) -> Integer.compare(score1.getScore(), score2.getScore())
```